# Is there a gem that builds a navigation <ul> from routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation

I've been using the simple-navigation for all my Rails menu building needs and it's great. But a thought just hit me.

Is there any gem that does the generation of a typical unordered-list used for generating navigation menus simply by interoperating with the `routes.rb` file?

Alternatively, is there any good coding practice for generating re-usable navigation trees programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate one with `simple-navigation` by looping over the routeset: `Rails.application.routes.routes`

Comment: Thanks. That's precisely what I thought could be done. I'll give it a try. If you have a code example to share, that will b cool too.